# How to import Aave and Uniswap contracts from a 0.8.x Solidity contract

Tags: solidity, truffle, uniswap, aave

So I have some smart contracts with version pragmas set to 0.8.0, my Truffle config's solc is set to 0.8.2 and everything compiles except for some imported contracts from Aave and Uniswap.

This is what I get from the terminal when I run the compile command:

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling @aave\protocol-v2\contracts\interfaces\IAToken.sol
> Compiling @aave\protocol-v2\contracts\interfaces\ILendingPool.sol
> Compiling @aave\protocol-v2\contracts\interfaces\ILendingPoolAddressesProvider.sol
> Compiling @aave\protocol-v2\contracts\interfaces\IPriceOracle.sol
> Compiling @aave\protocol-v2\contracts\misc\AaveProtocolDataProvider.sol
> Compiling @chainlink\contracts\src\v0.8\Chainlink.sol
> Compiling @chainlink\contracts\src\v0.8\interfaces\ChainlinkRequestInterface.sol
> Compiling @chainlink\contracts\src\v0.8\interfaces\ENSInterface.sol
> Compiling @chainlink\contracts\src\v0.8\interfaces\LinkTokenInterface.sol
> Compiling @chainlink\contracts\src\v0.8\interfaces\OperatorInterface.sol
> Compiling @chainlink\contracts\src\v0.8\interfaces\OracleInterface.sol
> Compiling @chainlink\contracts\src\v0.8\interfaces\PointerInterface.sol
> Compiling @chainlink\contracts\src\v0.8\vendor\BufferChainlink.sol
> Compiling @chainlink\contracts\src\v0.8\vendor\CBORChainlink.sol
> Compiling @chainlink\contracts\src\v0.8\vendor\ENSResolver.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts-upgradeable\access\AccessControlUpgradeable.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts-upgradeable\access\IAccessControlUpgradeable.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts-upgradeable\proxy\ERC1967\ERC1967UpgradeUpgradeable.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts-upgradeable\proxy\beacon\IBeaconUpgradeable.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts-upgradeable\proxy\utils\Initializable.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts-upgradeable\proxy\utils\UUPSUpgradeable.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts-upgradeable\security\PausableUpgradeable.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts-upgradeable\token\ERC721\ERC721Upgradeable.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts-upgradeable\token\ERC721\IERC721ReceiverUpgradeable.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts-upgradeable\token\ERC721\IERC721Upgradeable.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts-upgradeable\token\ERC721\extensions\IERC721MetadataUpgradeable.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts-upgradeable\utils\AddressUpgradeable.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts-upgradeable\utils\ContextUpgradeable.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts-upgradeable\utils\CountersUpgradeable.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts-upgradeable\utils\StorageSlotUpgradeable.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts-upgradeable\utils\StringsUpgradeable.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts-upgradeable\utils\introspection\ERC165Upgradeable.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts-upgradeable\utils\introspection\IERC165Upgradeable.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\access\AccessControl.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\access\IAccessControl.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\proxy\ERC1967\ERC1967Proxy.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\proxy\ERC1967\ERC1967Upgrade.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\proxy\Proxy.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\proxy\beacon\IBeacon.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\token\ERC20\ERC20.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\token\ERC20\IERC20.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\token\ERC20\extensions\IERC20Metadata.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\token\ERC20\utils\SafeERC20.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\token\ERC721\ERC721.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\token\ERC721\IERC721.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\token\ERC721\IERC721Receiver.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\token\ERC721\extensions\IERC721Metadata.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\utils\Address.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\utils\Context.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\utils\StorageSlot.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\utils\Strings.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\utils\introspection\ERC165.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\utils\introspection\IERC165.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\utils\math\Math.sol
> Compiling @openzeppelin\contracts\utils\structs\EnumerableSet.sol
> Compiling @uniswap\v2-periphery\contracts\interfaces\IUniswapV2Router01.sol
> Compiling @uniswap\v2-periphery\contracts\interfaces\IUniswapV2Router02.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\AaveAssetManager.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\BaseAssetManager.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\ConvertLib.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\DataTypes.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\EToken.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\FlightDelayRiskModule.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\LPManualWhitelist.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\MetaCoin.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\Migrations.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\Policy.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\PolicyNFT.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\PolicyPool.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\PolicyPoolComponent.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\PolicyPoolConfig.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\RiskModule.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\TrustfulRiskModule.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\WadRayMath.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\dependencies\ChainlinkClientUpgradeable.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\mocks\FixedRateAssetManager.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\mocks\ForwardProxy.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\mocks\FreeGrantInsolvencyHook.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\mocks\IMintableERC20.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\mocks\LPInsolvencyHook.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\mocks\LinkTokenMock.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\mocks\PolicyPoolMock.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\mocks\TestCurrency.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\mocks\TestNFT.sol
> Compiling .\interfaces\IAssetManager.sol
> Compiling .\interfaces\IEToken.sol
> Compiling .\interfaces\IInsolvencyHook.sol
> Compiling .\interfaces\ILPWhitelist.sol
> Compiling .\interfaces\IPolicyNFT.sol
> Compiling .\interfaces\IPolicyPool.sol
> Compiling .\interfaces\IPolicyPoolComponent.sol
> Compiling .\interfaces\IPolicyPoolConfig.sol
> Compiling .\interfaces\IRiskModule.sol

> Compilation warnings encountered:

    Warning: SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. Before publishing, consider adding a comment containing "SPDX-License-Identifier: <SPDX-License>" to each source file. Use "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED" for non-open-source code. Please see https://spdx.org for more information.--> @uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router01.sol

,Warning: SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. Before publishing, consider adding a comment containing "SPDX-License-Identifier: <SPDX-License>" to each source file. Use "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED" for non-open-source code. Please see https://spdx.org for more information.   
--> @uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol


ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.8.2+commit.661d1103.Emscripten.clang) - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
 --> @aave/protocol-v2/contracts/interfaces/IAToken.sol:2:1:
  |
2 | pragma solidity 0.6.12;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

,ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.8.2+commit.661d1103.Emscripten.clang) - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
 --> @aave/protocol-v2/contracts/interfaces/ILendingPool.sol:2:1:
  |
2 | pragma solidity 0.6.12;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

,ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.8.2+commit.661d1103.Emscripten.clang) - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
 --> @aave/protocol-v2/contracts/interfaces/ILendingPoolAddressesProvider.sol:2:1:
  |
2 | pragma solidity 0.6.12;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

,ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.8.2+commit.661d1103.Emscripten.clang) - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
 --> @aave/protocol-v2/contracts/interfaces/IPriceOracle.sol:2:1:
  |
2 | pragma solidity 0.6.12;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

,ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.8.2+commit.661d1103.Emscripten.clang) - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
 --> @aave/protocol-v2/contracts/misc/AaveProtocolDataProvider.sol:2:1:
  |
2 | pragma solidity 0.6.12;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


Error: Truffle is currently using solc 0.8.2, but one or more of your contracts specify "pragma solidity 0.6.12".
Please update your truffle config or pragma statement(s).
(See https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration#compiler-configuration for information on
configuring Truffle to use a specific solc compiler version.)
```

Is there a way to get everything to compile?

Answer (score 2):

These errors indicate that the contract you're trying to import was written for Solidity 0.6.12. There are two ways to deal with this if you're on a different Solidity version: import the ABI JSON or port the contracts.

#### Method 1: Import ABI JSON

Truffle 5 has a feature just for a situation like this. As long as you only want to interact with already deployed contracts through interfaces, the interfaces can be generated automatically from the ABI definitions and they will match the Solidity version you're using:

[Take a Dive into Truffle 5 > Compilation of abi.json files](https://trufflesuite.com/blog/take-a-dive-into-truffle-5/index.html#compilation-of-abijson-files)

> ##### Compilation of abi.json files
>
> Another exciting addition to Truffle is the ability to compile from a contract’s ABI. When you create a JSON source file in your “contracts” directory that contains a contract’s ABI, Truffle will take it, use it to create an interface, and compile it. This might come in handy, for example, when you want to import and use a library that requires a different version of the Solidity compiler than the importing file. You can then simply compile the library and create a new JSON file containing the ABI of the imported library. Under the hood Truffle will compile the ABI into a Solidity interface and create an artifact for it. You will then be able to import the interface into your contract!

According to [aave/protocol-v2 > Getting Started](https://github.com/aave/protocol-v2#getting-started):

> The JSON artifacts with the ABI and Bytecode are also included into the bundled NPM package at `artifacts/` directory.

#### Method 2: Port the contracts

The alternative is to copy the files you need to your own repository and fix all compilation errors.

If the only thing you need are interfaces, then this should be relatively safe and simple. Porting these might be as easy as just bumping version in the pragma.

Unlike with the ABI JSON, you can use this method also if you want to to use their contracts directly, i.e. inherit from them and call internal methods, it'll just be harder. Getting them to compile might not actually be that hard in itself, but every breaking change introduces some semantic changes that make code behave differently in specific situations. If you decide to do this, make sure the code you're porting is well covered with tests and they all pass. Then take a good look at the list of breaking changes in the compiler:

- [Solidity v0.7.0 Breaking Changes](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/070-breaking-changes.html)
- [Solidity v0.8.0 Breaking Changes](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/080-breaking-changes.html)

Especially the section called "Silent Changes of the Semantics". That should be the last resort though. If you need more than interfaces I'd seriously consider just staying at a lower version of the compiler.