# What pragma version to use?

Tags: solidity, solc, compilation

When I start with a project and have to decide which **pragma** I want to use, what are the main things I have to consider?

For simplicity, lets first assume I start a project from scratch, without importing any dependencies; is there any reason to use an older pragma than the *latest stable version* (which I think should be `0.8.10` by the time of this writing)?

What if I rely on third party packages that use `^0.6.0` pragma for example. How will this impact the choice of the pragma I choose. What if I even import several packages with different major pragma version such as `^0.6.0` and another using `^0.8.0` which does not require `safemath`anymore?

Is there ***anything else*** I have to take into consideration when choosing the pragma?

Comment: Regarding importing packages with different versions, see [How to import Aave and Uniswap contracts from a 0.8.x Solidity contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/115579/how-to-import-aave-and-uniswap-contracts-from-a-0-8-x-solidity-contract/).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, you wrote some great answers there. My key takeaways from reading your posts are, in a nutshell:
1) that its usually best to chose the latest version of solidity (given it is supported by the libraries/frameworks I use)
2) and that most (all?) compatibility issues with imported contracts can be solved by compiling the contracts ABI with the desired solidity version or by porting the contract.

Comment: Pretty much. Though I have to admit that staying on the latest version will not always be easy. Using the ABI is only an option if you want to interact with an already deployed instance of the contract rather than use it as a set of utilities and base contracts to inherit from. Porting a large contract may not be easy and could potentially introduce some subtle security issues. My advice is basically: when in doubt try the latest first and go for lower only when forced to.